# Accessing Serial Port from Ethernet

Tags: network-printer, serial-port

I currently managing 2 POS Devices in a Restaurant. The POS is using Windows 7.

1 POS located on the first floor has a printer connected via COM1 port. The printer itself has a LPT Port, the printer comes with a LPT to COM Port.
1 POS located on the second floor doesn't has any printer. (more like an Ordering Station)

What i want is when i ordered from the ordering station i want to print the orders to the printer on the first floor.

I used a software from [HHD Software](https://www.hhdsoftware.com/remote-serial-ports), it works like a charm. But since it was on beta, the trial period is expired today.

Other methods i have tried :

  1. Sharing the printer like any modern printer : failed.

  2. creating a TCP/IP Port by typing the 1st Floor POS : failed.

  3. Searching international forum for my case : from what i found, all refering to use (and buy) softwares for it.

My question is : is there anyway to share the COM port from 1st Floor POS so it's accessible from POS on 2nd floor directly from Windows without using anykind of softwares?

Comment: If you have a router/modem, that one could have a wireless port - so, since your printer is very old (LPT and COM) - a new printer with wifi could be a better solution, accessible from two computers, via router.

Comment: @Yoan Yes changing the device to modern printer is always an options. But, i would like to keep that options as a last measure. Thanks for suggesting :)

Comment: @harrymc I already read the software solutions in that thread, which replies indicating what i tried number 3. So if it's possible, i would like to try any settings in Windows that doesn't require buying softwares or hardwares.
But i'll leave it to moderators whether this is a duplicate thread or not :)

Answer (score 0):

> **is there anyway to share the COM port from 1st Floor POS so it's accessible from POS on 2nd floor directly from Windows without using anykind of softwares?**

Since you mention TCP/IP, I infer that both POS terminals are connected by Ethernet.

There are a number of ways to allow both POS terminals to print to a common printer.

1. Both Windows and Linux allow for sharing of local printers. The software is built-in. Just look up [printer-sharing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4089224/windows-10-share-network-printer) for your POS O/S.
2. Connect the printer using a traditional Print-Server - this is a small box with connectors for power, Ethernet and parallel-port. An example is a [HP JetDirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetDirect#External_print_servers). If the POS terminals are Windows-based or Linux-based  you can then configure an LPC/LPD client service there to use the LPD protocol to print to the print-server. Most print servers also support a variety of other printing protocols including direct-TCP-port (9100), FTP, etc.
3. Use a reverse terminal-server, a small dedicated box that has an Ethernet connection and one or several serial ports. For example, Perle still make the [IOLAN](https://storeuk.perle.com/iolan-ds1-gr)

   > A Serial to Ethernet solution to web or network enable equipment with RS232, RS422 or RS485 serial interfaces.
4. Replace the existing printer with a network-capable printer. For example any HP Laserjet whose model number includes an "N" suffix. Some other manufacturers use a similar convention. If you are using a specialised POS thermal printer which prints receipts on long rolls of thermal paper, there may also be varieties of those printers that are network capable.

Comment: Thanks for replying :)
Yes both POS are connected by ethernet. 

As i mention before, i tried sharing the printers (\\<computer name\<printer name or "<printer name> on <computer name>") from 1st Floor POS, so 2nd Floor POS can install that shared printer, but nothing will come out if i input from 2nd floor POS. No problem when i input on 1st floor POS.

Buying any Hardware or software is always an options for me. But in this chance, i would rather try any Windows settings to do that.

Answer (score -1):

The solution consists of two parts:

- Understanding, that this is extremely easy in the Unix world
- Understanding, thet all relevat parts are ported to CygWin

In the Unix world, one would use `stty` to set the port parameters (baud rate etc.), then `nc` (also known as netcat) to link the serial port to a TCP port.

We do not need `stty`, as the serial port parameters can be set from the command line via `mode`, and nc is available as a CygWin package.

Comment: I might look into this Cygwin. I don't have any experience dealing with it, but i will try. :)